# Convention for the attribute used for optimistic locking?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, optimistic-locking

I am doing optimistic locking on some rows in dynamodb. I'm wondering is there a convention for the attribute key name used for the OL version number? I'm thinking

```
_v: 1
```

Comment: Not really. You can use something more verbose like `recordVersion`, or `itemVersion`, or something more concise like your proposal, or `ver` etc. It's up to you, but it does make sense to be consistent in your own systems.

Answer (score 0):

In the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html) they use a field called `version`. I also use that field name, because we just copied AWS.

You can use any field name you want. A very short field name has the benefit of saving you RCUs on Scans and Queries. It probably won't matter but keeping field names short can save you some expense, especially if your values are quite short (and therefore the field names make up a lot of the table data).